# Is there a way in javascript to keep a button thats been clicked active after clicking on another part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to keep my button with a class of active when clicked (which changes the color of the button) to stay that color until another button is being clicked. But right now if I click a button and then click another part of the page the button turns back to its original pre-clicked color.

I have tried implementing different javascript measures but am always met with some sort of function error.

This is the current script that I am working with so maybe it is interfering with anything new I try to add

```js
const myFunction_date_night = () => {
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_date-night").style.display ='block';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_date-night").style.display ='block';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-date-night").style.display ='block';
    document.getElementById("timeline-day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-night-out").style.display ='none'
}

const myFunction_day_out_with_kids = () => {
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("timeline-day-out-with-kids").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("timeline-saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-night-out").style.display ='none'
}

const myFunction_saturday_mornings = () => {
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_saturday-mornings").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_saturday-mornings").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("timeline-day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-saturday-mornings").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("timeline-workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-night-out").style.display ='none'
}

const myFunction_workday_downtown = () => { 
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_workday-downtown").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_workday-downtown").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_night-out").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("timeline-day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-workday-downtown").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("timeline-night-out").style.display ='none'
}


const myFunction_night_out = () => {
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_image_night-out").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("outings-list_title_night-out").style.display ='block'
    document.getElementById("timeline-date-night").style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById("timeline-day-out-with-kids").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-saturday-mornings").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-workday-downtown").style.display ='none'
    document.getElementById("timeline-night-out").style.display ='block'
}
```

Below is my CSS for the buttons

```css
.outings-list.et_pb_bg_layout_light.et_pb_button:hover,
.outings-list.et_pb_bg_layout_light.et_pb_button:focus,
.outings-list.et_pb_bg_layout_light.et_pb_button.is-active,
.outings-list.et_pb_bg_layout_light.et_pb_button.active {
    background-color: #ffbe00 !important;
    border-color: #ffbe00 !important;
    color: #232323 !important;
}
```

I tried adding this script with

```js
const myFunction_date_night = () => {
    $('.outings-list.et_pb_bg_layout_light.et_pb_button').removeClass('active-button');
    $(this).addClass('active-button');
}
```

This is the css that it is being added

```css
.active-button {
    background-color: #ffbe00 !important;
    border-color: #ffbe00 !important;
    color: #232323 !important;
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at myFunction_date_night ((index):328:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Considering `$ is not a function` error, you haven't included jQuery.

Comment: (Also, whatever element you are using, (`<button>`?), there might be more suitable approaches for making them "exclusive", such as group of named radio inputs, or select. If you really *must* use buttons, use `aria-pressed="true"` attribute rather than `is_active` or similar  class.)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have this in my header thinking that would work. But still have the same error. 
<script src=”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js”></script>
****side note, i am very new at javascript.

Comment: In addition to everything said, it looks like the OP needs a solution for _**tabbed content**_. There is tons of code, but regarding accessibility, one could go with [one of the patterns of the **ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)**](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/examples/tabs-manual/).